# QGIS-Server does not process Temporary Scratch Layers available in QGIS-project

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-server, memory-layer

I have a virtual server running under Windows Server 2016 Standard.
And I have QGIS Server version 3.22.13 deployed and successfully functioning on it.
I use QWC version 1 as a web-client on my server. And everything works fine with regular (and even virtual) vector layers.
QGIS Desktop 3.22.13 is also installed on my server. And for QGIS Desktop, a wonderful plugin "Memory Layer Saver" is installed (it allows you to save Temporary Scratch Layers available in QGIS-projects to a separate *.mldata file).

Therefore, in the QGIS Desktop itself installed on the server, Temporary Scratch Layers are successfully saved alongside the QGIS-project file and are successfully displayed on the QGIS Desktop map.
But in the web-client, although they are added as layers in the Legend (symbols corresponding to these layers are also displayed), they are not displayed on the map itself.

Maybe it is still possible to solve the problem by installing the "Memory Layer Saver" plugin on the QGIS Server itself or in some other way. If this is possible, then, unfortunately, I do not know how to do it correctly.
Can anyone in this case (which I hope with all my heart) tell me how to do it.

Or is it that QGIS Server cannot in principle read, process and render such Temporary Scratch Layers (saved by the "Memory Layer Saver" plugin to the *.mldata file)?

Comment: Only the plugin knows about those mldata files. Your server will need a plugin to discover and load them. It might be a great feature request to the plugin developers to port it to QGIS server too.